# "Cannot find module" when importing JSON file from absolute path

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, ecmascript-6, vite

Currently I'm getting the error `Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations` on a JSON file that I'm trying to import.

I've migrated all my JSON files to a data folder and have tried to implement absolute pathing in the `vite.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json` files.

When I employ the absolute path, I get auto-complete, hinting that things should be working, but I get the error. When I do relative paths (`../../../assets/data/aboutData.json`) the code works fine.

What do I need to change about my import strategy or config files to make this work? Thanks ahead of time.

**About.tsx: (line 1 is where the error is happening)**

```
import aboutData from 'src/assets/data/aboutData.json';
import { Card } from './Card'


export function About() {
    return (
        <div>
            {aboutData.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card
                        key={index}
                        img={item.img}
                        cardHeading={item.title}
                        cardText={item.body}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**aboutData.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": /* id */,
        "img": /* image path */,
        "title": /* title */,
        "body": /* text body */
    },
    // remainder of JSON file
]
```

**vite.config.ts:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: './src',
        },
    },
});
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    // options
    "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["/src/*"]
        }
    },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Your `src` path is mapped incorrectly. It's highly unlikely the `src` directory is in the root of your filesystem so `/src/*` is most probably wrong

Comment: Ah, should it be `./src` instead?

Comment: That would be my guess. Try it and see?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I also had to use fetch instead of import on my json, as the browser was flagging security issues, but that's a different thing entirely. Thanks for pointing that out. I never would have caught that.

Comment: You should definitely be able to import a `.json` file which would be handled by Vite, not the browser